# MPI_Scatterv (c) will give segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi

I've built a fairly simple c code that reads a pgm image, splits it in different sections and sends it to various cores to elaborate it.

In order to account for some elaboration margins (each core has to access a larger area of the image than the it needs to write on), I can't simply split the image but I first have to create an array where I add the before mentioned margins.

As a quick example: an image is 1600x1200 (width x height), I have 2 cores, I want to access an area of 3x3 centered on the pixel and I'm splitting this image horizontal line by horizontal line then the subdivision would be -> the first core gets the pixels from 0 to 601*1600, the second core gets the pixels from 509*1600 to 1200*1600.

Now, I believe there is nothing wrong in how I implemented this in my program, still I get this error:

```
[ct1pt-tnode003:22389:0:22389] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x7ffe7f60ead8)
==== backtrace (tid:  22389) ====
 0 0x000000000004ee05 ucs_debug_print_backtrace()  ???:0
 1 0x0000000000402624 main()  ???:0
 2 0x0000000000022505 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
 3 0x0000000000400d99 _start()  ???:0
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "testlibscatter.h"
#include <mpi.h>

#define MSGLEN 2048


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int m = atoi(argv[1]), n = atoi(argv[2]), kern_type = atoi(argv[3]);
double kernel[m*n];
int i_rank, ranks;
int param, symm;

MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &i_rank);
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ranks);

int xsize, ysize, maxval;
xsize = 0;
ysize = 0;
maxval = 0;

void * ptr;

switch (kern_type){
    case 1:
    meankernel(m, n, kernel);
    break;
    case 2:
    weightkernel(m, n, param, kernel);
    break;
    case 3:
    gaussiankernel(m, n, param, symm, kernel);
    break;
}

if (i_rank == 0){
    read_pgm_image(&ptr, &maxval, &xsize, &ysize, "check_me2.pgm");
}


MPI_Bcast(&xsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&ysize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&maxval, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

int flo, start, end, i;
flo = floor(ysize/ranks);

int first, last;

first = start - (m - 1)/2;
last = end + (m - 1)/2;

if (start == 0){
    first = 0;
}
if (end == ysize){
    last = ysize;
}

int sendcounts[ranks];
int displs[ranks];

int first2[ranks];
int last2[ranks];
int c_start2[ranks];
int c_end2[ranks];

int num;
num = (ranks - 1) * (m-1);
printf("num is %d\n", num);

unsigned short int bigpic[xsize*(ysize + num)];


if (i_rank == 0){
    for(i = 0; i < ranks; i++){
        c_start2[i] = i * flo;
        c_end2[i] = (i + 1) * flo; 
        if ( i == ranks - 1){
            c_end2[i] = ysize;
        }
        first2[i] = c_start2[i] - (m - 1)/2;
        last2[i] = c_end2[i] + (m - 1)/2;
        if (c_start2[i] == 0){
            first2[i] = 0;
        }
        if (c_end2[i] == ysize){
            last2[i] = ysize;
        }
        sendcounts[i] = (last2[i] - first2[i]) * xsize; 
    }

    int i, j, k, index, index_disp = 0;
    index = 0;
    displs[0] = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < ranks; k++){
        for (i = first2[k]*xsize; i < last2[k]*xsize; i++){
            bigpic[index] = ((unsigned short int *)ptr)[i];
            index++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", displs[index_disp]);
        index_disp++;
        displs[index_disp] = index;
    }

}

MPI_Bcast(displs, ranks, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(sendcounts, ranks, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

unsigned short int minipic[xsize*(last-first)];
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Scatterv(&bigpic[0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT, minipic, (last-first)*xsize, MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

the function kernel simply returns an array of m*n doubles to edit the image, while the read_pgm_image returns a void pointer with the values of the image read.
I've tried printing the values of `bigpic` and they show no problem.

Comment: Compile with `-g -O0` to generate debug info, and get a stack trace to find which line is crashing. If still stuck, trim down your code to a [mcve] and update your post. The error does not seem to happen in MPI fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code shown here, `start` and `end` are used uninitialised in the computations of `first` and `last`:

```c
int flo, start, end, i;
         ~~~~~~~~~~
flo = floor(ysize/ranks);

int first, last;

first = start - (m - 1)/2; // <---- start has a random value here
last = end + (m - 1)/2;    // <---- end has a random value here
```

If the values are very large, the size of `minipic` may become larger than the stack size:

```c
unsigned short int minipic[xsize*(last-first)];
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ random (possibly large) value
```

A strong indication that this is indeed the cause is the fact that the address of the fault `0x7ffe7f60ead8` is very close to the end of the positive part of the virtual address space, which is where most 64-bit OSes allocate the stack area of the main thread.

Always compile with `-Wall` in order to get back as many diagnostic messages from the compiler as possible.